# Conection MVVM Light with SelectionChanged

Tags: binding, uwp, mvvm-light

I'm creating app in UWP and i have question.
Can I somehow connection MVVM Light with SelectionChanged event (e.g. ListView) or with other event? 
I would like that when I will click on some Item in ListView then I call SelectionChanged.

How do I do?

Comment: Any updates on this issue? If you have any other concern regarding this issue, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the Method in ViewModel ,and use the `x:bind` to connection ViewModel.

The MVVMLight's method is use in WPF that cant bind the event in Method.

UWP can use `x:bind` to bind the UI event to ViewModel.

The sample:

XAML:

```
<ListView SelectionChanged = "{x:bind view.SelectionChanged }"/>
```

XAML.cs:

```
private ViewModel View{set;get;}
```

ViewModel:

```
public void SelectionChanged()
{

}
```

You can use ItemClick event that will run when you click the ListViewItem .

Answer (score 0):

Inside your viewmodel something *.cs

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, Action<object> execute)
    {
        this._canExecute = canExecute;
        this._execute = execute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    private ICommand _doSelectionChangedCommand;
    public ICommand DoSelectionChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_doSelectionChangedCommand == null)
            {
                _doSelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    p => this.CanSelectionChanged,
                    p => this.DoSomeImportantMethod());
            }
            return _doSomething;
        }
    }
}
```

In your viewSomemthing.xaml
--For namespace

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

--Then go down to your control, we'll use Combobox as an example

```
<ComboBox ... />
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoSelectionChangedCommand}"/>              
    </EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```